# Problems parsing URL with JSON to FullCalendar

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the full calendar from www.fullcalendar.io passing a URL that returns a JSON formatted data:

```
[
    {"id":"29041412","start":"2029-04-14T12:00","end":"2029-04-14T1:00","title":"Victor"},
    {"id":"28041411","start":"2028-04-14T11:00","end":"2028-04-14T2030:00","title":"nani"},
    {"id":"15051417","start":"2015-05-14T17:00","end":"2015-05-14T2029:00","title":"nani"},
    {"id":"29041411","start":"2029-04-14T11:00","end":"2029-04-14T2016:00","title":"papapa"},
    {"id":"30041411","start":"2030-04-14T11:00","end":"2030-04-14T2030:00","title":"baiak"},
    {"id":"30041417","start":"2030-04-14T17:00","end":"2030-04-14T2031:00","title":"iepwpamxb"},
    {"id":"15051412","start":"2015-05-14T12:00","end":"2015-05-14T2031:00","title":"lala"}
]
```

I try to follow and edit a demo that is inside the package of full calendar but it show example with json file, not with URL. I not find the solution for pass the URL that returns this data and the full calendar put events in the calendar.
I take format of my json from the json explained in the web.

this is my php code:

```
// Read and parse our events JSON file into an array of event data arrays.
$json = file_get_contents('http://***/diary_service_natursais.php?method=getEntireBooking');
$input_arrays = json_decode($json, true);

// Accumulate an output array of event data arrays.
$output_arrays = array();
foreach ($input_arrays as $array) {

    // Convert the input array into a useful Event object
    $event = new Event($array, $timezone);

    // If the event is in-bounds, add it to the output
    if ($event->isWithinDayRange($range_start, $range_end)) {
        $output_arrays[] = $event->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: `http://***/diary_service_natursais.php?method=getEntireBooking` is return a valid JSON formatted file?

Comment: If I put the URL in the explorer, in explorar appear these:[
    {"id":"29041412","start":"2029-04-14T12:00","end":"2029-04-14T1:00","title":"Victor"},
    {"id":"28041411","start":"2028-04-14T11:00","end":"2028-04-14T2030:00","title":"nani"},
    {"id":"15051417","start":"2015-05-14T17:00","end":"2015-05-14T2029:00","title":"nani"},
    {"id":"29041411","start":"2029-04-14T11:00","end":"2029-04-14T2016:00","title":"papapa"},
    {"id":"30041411","start":"2030-04-14T11:00","end":"2030-04-14T2030:00","title":"kaiak"}
]

Comment: Why are you converting the JSON this way? It can be passed straight to FullCalendar...

Comment: Like this:
 <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
     left: 'prev, next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    defaultdate: '2014-09-12',
    editale: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    events:{
     url: 'http://***/diary_service_natursais.php?method=getEntireBooking',
     error: function(){
      $('#script-warning').show();
???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define Event object. You can try to include [this](https://github.com/Bruno17/migxCalendars/blob/master/assets/components/migxcalendars/js/demos/php/utils.php) file as follow:

```
require './utils.php';
```

then you need to define $range_start and $range_end variables with date format as yyyy-mm-dd

You can check [this](https://github.com/Bruno17/migxCalendars/blob/master/assets/components/migxcalendars/js/demos/php/get-events.php) example.

Comment: This example is the same I use to test. Is included inside the full calendar-2.1.1.zip package. In this example I substitute this: $json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../json/events.json'); with this:$json = file_get_contents('http://.../webservice.php');